# Scroll Flexbox dashboard problem CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

When creating my dashboard with flexbox css html, I have a scroll problem for example:

In the middle red container if I make it vertical the horizontal one does not work well for me opteniendo results like it expands the container descuadrando the design.

If I work the horizontal scroll does not work the vertical scroll expanding this.

I want it to work like this in the following image:

Desired result

[image: 1]

I have tried many things with the flexbox like setting the height or width to 100% and even forcing the scroll, but I can't get the expected effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, you should post your current solution next time to see which part is not working. For example, I couldn't really tell if the vertical scrollbar in the middle region is supposed to scroll the top or the middle part. Anyways, if you're set on using flexboxes, here's a way to do it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.left__header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.middle__header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.middle__body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.middle__footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left__header">1</div>
    <div class="left__body"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="middle__header">
      <!-- Fixed width to simulate overflowing content -->
      <div style="min-width: 2000px">1 2 3 4 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle__body">
      <!-- Fixed height to simulate overflowing content -->
      <div style="min-height: 2000px">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle__footer">
      Pia de Pagina
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    SideBar Right
  </div>
</main>
```

But if you don't plan on dynamically adding/removing elements or moving stuff around in the base layout (i.e. these regions stay the same during the use of the application) I'd recommend using CSS grid instead:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
    "left-header middle-header right" min-content 
    "left-body   middle-body   right" 
    "left-body   middle-footer right" min-content / 2fr 4fr 4fr;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left__header {
  grid-area: left-header;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left__body {
  grid-area: left-body;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.middle__header {
  grid-area: middle-header;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.middle__body {
  grid-area: middle-body;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.middle__footer {
  grid-area: middle-footer;
  background-color: white;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="left__header">1</div>
  <div class="left__body"></div>

  <div class="middle__header">
    <!-- Fixed width to simulate overflowing content -->
    <div style="min-width: 2000px">1 2 3 4 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle__body">
    <!-- Fixed height to simulate overflowing content -->
    <div style="min-height: 2000px">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle__footer">
    Pia de Pagina
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    SideBar right
  </div>
</main>
```

This results in the same output, but the HTML/CSS is much more readable IMO. It uses the [`grid-template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template) property, which is fairly new, but should be available in [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid-template).